# How to sync Google Docs with a folder in my filesystem?

Tags: filesystem, sync

I'd like to be able to edit my files offline and it would automatically send the changes to Google Docs and vice versa. Is that even possible? If so, how to do it?

Comment: When google release google drive for linux, then you can use that! I have it for my workspace for eclipse. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [google-docs-fs](https://launchpad.net/google-docs-fs)

```
sudo apt-get install google-docs-fs
```